# C++ How do I set the fractional part of a float?

Tags: c++, floating-point, double

I know how to get the fractional part of a float but I don't know how to set it. I have two integers returned by a function, one holds the integer and the other holds the fractional part.
For example:

```
int a = 12;
int b = 2; // This can never be 02, 03 etc
float c;
```

How do I get `c` to become 12.2? I know I could add something like `(float)b \ 10` but then what if b is >= than 10? Then I would have to divide by 100, and so on. Is there a function or something where I can do `setfractional(c, b)`?

Thanks

edit: The more I think about this problem the more I realize how illogical it is. if b == 1 then it would be 12.1 but if b == 10 it would also be 12.1 so I don't know how I'm going to handle this. I'm guessing the function never returns a number >= 10 for fractional but I don't know.

Comment: um, what? In this scheme, how would you expect to represent the number `3.004`?

Comment: I can't think of any legitimate reason for wanting to do this. What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: OR 12.0123 or 12.00123.  I can see if b was "tenths" or "hundredths", not just "fractional".  What about implementing fractional part as "numerator" and "denominator" (isn't that what a fraction is???)

Comment: I'm trying to accomplish what I said in the question. But as I said in my edit I'm at a loss to explain why the fractional part is returned as an integer.

Comment: so you didn't write the original function? If it actually works like that, whoever wrote it put no thought into it. You might want to find a different library.

Comment: At least in a typical case, this is implemented as the fractional part being a count of some fraction (e.g., thousandths). In that case, you'd just convert to floating point and divide by the specified denominator.

Comment: c = (float) a + (float) b / 10.2?  In other words, divide the second number by 10.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

kindly try this below code after including include math.h and stdlib.h file:

```
 int a=12;

 int b=22;

 int d=b;

 int i=0;

 float c;

while(d>0)

{

d/=10;

i++;

}

c=a+(float)b/pow(10,i);
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but before you're asking why you've been downvoted, those could be the reasons: your answer is badly formatted, doesn't provide any explanation (although being a mixture of both Xanatos' and my answer), and it encourages to include C headers on a C++ question.

Comment: needs explanation

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
float IntFrac(int integer, int frac)
{
    float integer2 = integer;
    float frac2 = frac;

    float log10 = log10f(frac2 + 1.0f);
    float ceil = ceilf(log10);
    float pow = powf(10.0f, -ceil);

    float res = abs(integer);
    res += frac2 * pow;

    if (integer < 0)
    {
        res = -res;
    }

    return res;
}
```

Ideone: http://ideone.com/iwG8UO

It's like saying: log10(98 + 1) = log10(99) = 1.995, ceilf(1.995) = 2, powf(10, -2) = 0.01, 99 * 0.01 = 0.99, and then 12 + 0.99 = 12.99 and then we check for the sign.

And let's hope the vagaries of IEEE 754 float math won't hit too hard :-)

I'll add that it would be probably better to use `double` instead of `float`. Other than 3d graphics, there are very few fields were using `float` is a good idea nowadays.

Comment: @user2672807 Corrected. Now the ideone has various tests

Comment: @EricPostpischil They are local variables, so I can

Comment: @EricPostpischil Sadly I can't find an autoritative reason for C++, but from http://c-faq.com/decl/namespace.html `4. All standard library identifiers with external linkage (e.g. function names) are always reserved as identifiers with external linkage.` `pow` clearly falls here, but local variables clearly don't fall here.

Answer (score 0):

The most trivial method would be counting the digits of `b` and then divide accordingly:

```
int i = 10;
while(b > i) // rather slow, there are faster ways
    i*= 10;

c = a + static_cast<float>(b)/i;
```

Note that due to the nature of `float` the result might not be what you expected. Also, if you want something like `3.004` you can modify the initial value of `i` to another power of ten.